# The circles aren't appearing at the front of the html website

Tags: javascript, html, css, scatter-plot

I'm trying to make a scatterplot, and I have the circles in the right place, but they're behind the graph for some reason, and I was wondering how to bring them to the front so that they show up.

When I inspect it, it shows that there is a circle there, but I can't actually see any of them.

```
scatterplot.js
```

```
d3.csv('NetflixOriginals.csv').then(function(data) {
    
    var csvg = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("id", "circles")
    .append("svg");
    var circles = csvg.selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            var date = new Date(d["Premiere"]);
            var cx = scaleDate(date);
            var cy = scaleIMDB(d["IMDB Score"]) - 300;
            return "translate(" + cx + " " + cy + ")";
        })
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", 1)
        .attr("cy", 1)
        // .attr("cx", function(d) {
        //     var date = new Date(d["Premiere"]);
        //     return scaleDate(date);
        // })
        // .attr("cy", function(d) {
        //     return scaleIMDB(d["IMDB Score"]);
        // })
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .style("fill",function(d) {
            if (d["IMDB Score"] > 7.5) {
                return "orange";
            } else {
                return "blue";
            }
        });
});

function scaleDate(date) {
    return dateScale(date);
}

function scaleIMDB(imdb) {
    return imdbScale(imdb);
}

var dateScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([new Date(2015, 0, 1), new Date(2022, 0, 1)]).range([60,700]);

var imdbScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([1,10]).range([340,20]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to messing around with z-index to put the graph behind?

```
z-index: -1;
```

Comment: yeah I tried doing that in the div but it didn't change anything

Comment: It'd be helpful to see your css code. Might be a positioning issue. You need to position (set the position property to anything other than static(defaut)) anything you want to give a z-index to.